# Where to deploy the Web Application?

Tags: facebook, web-applications, deployment

I have made a Facebook application (using C# and ASP.NET + SQL server), which is hosted on my localhost. Is there any other place where I can deploy this web application, so that it can be accessible from anywhere on the internet.

What changes should be made in the connection string, while deploying this on the internet???

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+free+hosting

Comment: I wouldn't use them. This is from their site: "AspSpider free hosting service is available for members only for educational purpose and is valid for 90 days from the date of creating the hosting account. After 90 days, you may re create your website under a different domain within AspSpider."

Comment: then create a new account or select a different domain ....
Atleast they are providing this service for free.

Answer (score 3):

Shop around for some web [.Net hosting](http://www.google.ch/search?hl=en&q=dotnet+hosting).

Looking for free web hosting of your .Net app? Try [monoforge](http://www.monoforge.com/). It's very unlikely to find free web hosting for Microsoft based products. It costs money. So, my advice is to try to retrofit your app to [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) and have it hosted on MonoForge.

Comment: i m looking for free web hosting!!!!

Comment: Dear Adi_aks, calm down, please. You don't have to yell at me.

Comment: @Adi_aks Boris is right, see my answer ... @Boris, +1 so you don't feel bad

Answer (score 0):

You will need a web server/host supporting ASP.NET and SQL server. There are a plenty of options available.